# Updating closures to Swift 3 - @escaping

Tags: xcode, escaping, closures, swift3

I've updated my code to Xcode 8.0 beta 6 but I got stuck with what seems to be about the new non escaping closure default. In the following code Xcode suggests to add `@escaping` in front of `completion:` in the first line of the below code, but that still won't compile and goes in circles. *

(**EDIT**: In fact, @escaping should be added in **after** `completion:`, as Xcode suggests. The alert may still show but cleaning and compiling will remove it.)* How should this code be re-written / fixed to work in the updated Swift 3?
I've had a look in the new manual but I couldn't find proper code samples.

```
func doSomething(withParameter parameter: Int, completion: () -> ()) {
    // Does something

    callSomeOtherFunc(withCompletion: completion)
  }

// Calling the method and execute closure 
doSomething(withParameter: 2) {
  // do things in closure
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

#### Swift 3: closure parameter attributes are now applied to the parameter *type*, and not the parameter itself

Prior to Swift 3, the closure attributes `@autoclosure` and `@noescape` used to be attributes to the closure *parameter*, but are now attributes to the parameter *type*; see the following accepted Swift evolution proposal:

- [SE-0049: Move @noescape and @autoclosure to be type attributes](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0049-noescape-autoclosure-type-attrs.md)

Your specific question pertain to parameter type attribute `@escaping` (for which the same new rule applies), as described in the accepted Swift evolution proposal to let closure parameters be non-escaping by default:

- [SE-0103: Make non-escaping closures the default](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md)

These proposals are now both implemented in the beta stage of Xcode 8 (see [release notes for Xcode 8 beta 6](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_6/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_6.pdf); dev. account login needed for access)

> ***New in Xcode 8 beta 6 - Swift Compiler: Swift Language***
>
> Closure parameters are non-escaping by default, rather than explicitly
>   being annotated with `@noescape`. Use `@escaping` to indicate that a
>   closure parameter may escape. `@autoclosure(escaping)` is now written as
>   `@autoclosure @escaping`. The annotations `@noescape` and
>   `@autoclosure(escaping)` are deprecated. (SE-0103)
>
> ...
>
> ***New in Xcode 8 beta – Swift and Apple LLVM Compilers: Swift Language***
>
> The `@noescape` and `@autoclosure` attributes must now be written 
>   before the parameter type instead of before the parameter name. [SE-0049]

Hence, you use the non-default `@escaping` attribute as follows; applied to the *type* of the closure parameter, rather than the parameter itself

```
func doSomething(withParameter parameter: Int, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    // ...
}
```

---

*(Including my answer to a question in an upvoted comment below, as comments are not persistent data on SO)*

> @Cristi Băluță: "What does escaping do? Never seen this keywords
>   before swift3 auto-conversion ... "

See e.g. the link to the [SE-0103 evolution proposal above](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md) (as well as the quoted text from the beta 6 release notes): previously, closure parameters were escaping by default (hence no need for the existence of an explicit annotation for escaping), but are now instead non-escaping, by default. Hence the addition of `@escaping` to explicitly annotate that a closure parameter may escape (contrary to its default behaviour). This also explains why `@noescape` is now deprecated (no need to annotate the default behaviour).

For explaining what it means that a closure parameter is escaping, I quote the [Language Reference - attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html):

> *"Apply this attribute to a parameter’s type in a method or function declaration to indicate that the parameter’s value can be stored for
>   later execution. This means that the value is allowed to outlive the
>   lifetime of the call."*

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer dfri. I actually did add @escaping in the right place before the parameter, I just noticed my mistake pointing that out in the description. Xcode would still complain as I described, but doing a clean up and compiling anyways finally removes the alerts.

Comment: @nontomatic happy to help.

Comment: What does escaping do? Never seen this keywords before swift3 auto-conversion and i don't think i lost anything.

Comment: @CristiBăluță see e.g. the link to the [SE-0103 evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md) above (as well as the quoted text from the beta 6 release notes): previously, closure parameters were escaping by default (hence no need for a annotation that they were escaping), but are now instead non-escaping. Hence the addition of `@escaping` to explicitly annotate that a close parameter may escape (contrary to its default behaviour). This also explains why `@noescape` is no deprecated (no need to annotate default behaviour).

Comment: But that still doesn't answer @CristiBăluță's answer. To me `escaping` sounds like running away & gives me feel like closure-function is going to run away :P. what does Escaping do?

Comment: @SagarR.Kothari Both the question and the answer is based on the fact that we know the difference between escaping and nonescaping closures, hence my previous  comment to CristiBăluță (answers _why_ this keyword now exists). For explaining what it does, I quote the lang. ref.: _"Apply this attribute to a parameter’s type in a method or function declaration to indicate that the parameter’s value can be stored for later execution. This means that the value is allowed to outlive the lifetime of the call."_.

Comment: @SagarR.Kothari For details, refer to [the Language Reference - Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html), as well as [the Language Guide - Closures (see section Escaping Closures)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Comment: Now it's very clear what it does, thanks. So they basically switched favouring one kind of programmer to the other, i'm the one affected because i pass closures in order to call them asynchronously, so i need escaping. I hope in the future they'll guess what i want to do with the closure and mark it for me.

Comment: Why if a closure parameter is optional I don´t have to mark it as @escaping?

Answer (score 23):

### `@noescape`

From xcode 8 beta 6 *`@noescape`* is the default. Prior to that, *`@escaping`* was the default. Anybody updating to swift 3.0 from previous versions might face this error.

You can not store a `@noescape` closure inside a variable. Because if you can store a closure inside a variable, you can execute the closure from anywhere in your code. But `@noescape` states that the closure parameter can not escape the body of the function.

This will give compiler error in Xcode 8

```
class MyClass {

    var myClosure: (() -> ())?

    func doSomething(finishBlock: () -> ()) {
        myClosure = finishBlock    // ‼️ Error: Assigning non-escaping parameter 'finishBlock' to an @escaping closure
    }
}
```

This will compile ok (explicitly write `@escaping`)

```
class MyClass {

    var myClosure: (() -> ())?

    func doSomething(finishBlock: @escaping () -> ()) {
        myClosure = finishBlock
    }
}
```

**Benefits of `@noescape`:**

- Compiler can optimize your code for better Performance
- Compiler can take care of memory management
- There is no need to use a weak reference to self in the closure

For details check out: [Make non-escaping closures the default](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md)