# UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate delegate method "nearly matches optional requirement"

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

I am implementing

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
```

But I'm getting the "nearly matches optional requirement" warning from the compiler. What's wrong with my declaration? I copied it right out of the documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `@escaping` attribute. It isn't shown in the documentation. But it *is* shown in the header. That's the place to copy from! Here's the correct declaration:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
```

Comment: copied from the comments of [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395513/how-to-handle-usernotifications-actions-in-ios-10/39426419?noredirect=1#comment66238962_39426419): `@escaping` means "this closure may be executed later". Compiler can easily optimize non-escaping closures which are often used in map, filter and such, Swift 3 has made it default. All completion handlers are executed when some task is completed -- later, so we need to annotate @escaping for all completion handlers in Swift 3