# Swift optional escaping closure parameter

Tags: swift, function, closures, option-type

Given:

```
typealias Action = () -> ()

var action: Action = { }

func doStuff(stuff: String, completion: @escaping Action) {
    print(stuff)
    action = completion
    completion()
}

func doStuffAgain() {
    print("again")
    action()
}

doStuff(stuff: "do stuff") { 
    print("swift 3!")
}

doStuffAgain()
```

Is there any way to make the `completion` parameter (and `action`) of type `Action?` and also keep `@escaping` ?

Changing the type gives the following error:

> @escaping attribute only applies to function types

Removing the `@escaping` attribute, the code compiles and runs, but doesn't seem to be correct since the `completion` closure is escaping the scope of the function.

Comment: "Removing the `@escaping` attribute, the code compiles and runs" - That's because, as described in [SR-2444](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2444), `Action?` is, by default, escaping. So, removing `@escaping` when using the optional closure accomplishes what you need.

Comment: Related: [Updating closures to Swift 3 - @escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063499/updating-closures-to-swift-3-escaping/).

Comment: type alias closures are escaping

Comment: Here's an [excellent article by Ole Begemann](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/optional-non-escaping-closures/) that describes why it's happening and some workarounds if you want optional parameters to be @noescape.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

There is a [SR-2552](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2522) reporting that `@escaping` is not recognizing function type alias. that's why the error `@escaping attribute only applies to function types`. you can workaround by expanding the function type in the function signature:

```
typealias Action = () -> ()

var action: Action? = { }

func doStuff(stuff: String, completion: (@escaping ()->())?) {
    print(stuff)
    action = completion
    completion?()
}

func doStuffAgain() {
    print("again")
    action?()
}

doStuff(stuff: "do stuff") {
    print("swift 3!")
}

doStuffAgain()
```

**EDIT 1:**:

I was actually under a xcode 8 beta version where the bug [SR-2552](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2522) was not resolved yet. fixing that bug, introduced a new one(the one you're facing) that is still open. see [SR-2444](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2444).

The workaround *@Michael Ilseman* pointed as a temporary solution is remove the `@escaping` attribute from optional function type, **that keep the function as escaping**.

```
func doStuff(stuff: String, completion: Action?) {...}
```

**EDIT 2:**:

The [SR-2444](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2444) has been closed stating explicitly that closures in parameters positions **are not** escaping and need them to be marked with `@escaping` to make them escaping, but the optional parameters **are** implicitly escaping, since `((Int)->())?` is a synonyms of `Optional<(Int)->()>`, optional closures are escaping.

Comment: Now getting `@escaping may only be applied to parameters of function type
func doStuff(stuff: String, completion: (@escaping ()->())?) {`

Comment: `a temporary solution is remove the @escaping attribute from optional function type, that keep the function as escaping.`  Can you explain this further?  The default semantic in swift 3 is non-escaping.  Although it compiles without @escaping I'm afraid it will cause problems by being treated as non-escaping.  Is that not true?

Comment: Upon further reading I see that SR-2444 says that all optional closures are treated as escaping, which is a complementary bug :)  I going to assume that when it is fixed the compile will warn us to make the change.

Comment: Maybe a little off topic; but how does this work for `@autoclosure`? One gets the same error there...

Comment: it's working without @escaping
__
func doStuff(stuff: String, completion: (()->())?) {

Answer (score 259):

from: [swift-users mailing list](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160905/003185.html)

> Basically, @escaping is valid only on closures in function parameter position. The noescape-by-default rule only applies to these closures at function parameter position, otherwise they are escaping. Aggregates, such as enums with associated values (e.g. Optional), tuples, structs, etc., if they have closures, follow the default rules for closures that are not at function parameter position, i.e. they are escaping.

So optional function parameter is @escaping by default.
@noeascape only apply to function parameter by default.

Comment: I think this adds most important information to the subject, it should be accepted answer.

Comment: The reasoned answer. How probable is it that this could change?

Comment: This makes sense since technically saying `(()->Void)?` is the same as saying you have `Optional<()->Void>` and in order for the `Optional` to maintain ownership it would have to only accept `@escaping` functions.

I'll third that this should be the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 26):

I ran into a similar problem because mixing `@escaping` and non-`@escaping` is very confusing, especially if you need to pass the closures around.

I ended up assigning a no-op default value to the closure parameter via `= { _ in }`, which I think makes more sense:

```
func doStuff(stuff: String = "do stuff",
        completion: @escaping (_ some: String) -> Void = { _ in }) {
     completion(stuff)
}

doStuff(stuff: "bla") {
    stuff in
    print(stuff)
}

doStuff() {
    stuff in
    print(stuff)
}
```

Comment: This is clean & pretty in implementation.

Comment: What if I want to check if this block nil/empty?

Comment: Bummer, this does not work for a protocol method. "Default argument not permitted in a protocol method" (Xcode 8.3.2).

Answer (score 18):

I got it working in Swift 3 without any warnings only this way:

```
func doStuff(stuff: String, completion: (()->())? ) {
    print(stuff)
    action = completion
    completion?()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The important thing to understand in the example is that if you change `Action` to `Action?` the closure *is* escaping. So, let's do what you propose:

```
typealias Action = () -> ()

var action: Action? = { }

func doStuff(stuff: String, completion: Action?) {
    print(stuff)
    action = completion
    completion?()
}
```

Okay, now we'll call `doStuff`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var prop = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doStuff(stuff: "do stuff") {
            print("swift 3!")
            print(prop) // error: Reference to property 'prop' in closure 
                        // requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
        }
    }
}
```

Well, that requirement only arises for escaping closures. So the closure is escaping. That's why you don't *mark* it escaping - it's escaping already.

Comment: Hi @matt, Thanks for the explanation
Are both same? 
~ func foo(_ closure: @ escaping () -> Void) {}
~ func bar(_ closure: ( () -> Void)? ) {}