# Trouble with non-escaping closures in Swift 3

Tags: swift, closures

I have an `extension Array` in the form of:

```
extension Array
{
    private func someFunction(someClosure: (() -> Int)?)
    {
        // Do Something
    }

    func someOtherFunction(someOtherClosure: () -> Int)
    {
        someFunction(someClosure: someOtherClosure)
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error: `Passing non-escaping parameter 'someOtherClosure' to function expecting an @escaping closure`.

Both closures are indeed non-escaping (by default), and explicitly adding `@noescape` to `someFunction` yields a warning indicating that this is the default in Swift 3.1.

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

-- UPDATE -- 
Screenshot attached:
[image]

Comment: where do you have that error? any screenshot or more info? everything is working fine for me with @escaping

Comment: You're not invoking someOtherClosure() inside the someOtherFunction so shouldn't it be an escaping closure? Swift is not my primary language.

Comment: @Lu_ added screenshot

Comment: func someOtherFunction(someOtherClosure: @escaping () -> Int)

Comment: Use the fix-it: click the circle and a fix-it is suggested

Comment: See https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/optional-non-escaping-closures/.

Comment: Related: [Swift 3 optional escaping closure parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39618803/2976878), see especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39846519/2976878).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already said, `Optional` closures are `escaping`. An addition though:

Swift 3.1 has a [withoutActuallyEscaping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2827967-withoutactuallyescaping) helper function that can be useful here. It marks a closure `escaping` only for its use inside a passed closure, so that you don't have to expose the `escaping` attribute to the function signature.

Can be used like this:

```
extension Array {

    private func someFunction(someClosure: (() -> Int)?) {
        someClosure?()
    }

    func someOtherFunction(someOtherClosure: () -> Int) {
        withoutActuallyEscaping(someOtherClosure) {
            someFunction(someClosure: $0)
        }
    }
}


let x = [1, 2, 3]

x.someOtherFunction(someOtherClosure: { return 1 })
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 6):

Optional closures are always escaping.

Why is that? That's because the optional (which is an enum) wraps the closure and internally saves it.

There is an excellent article about the quirks of `@escaping` [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/optional-non-escaping-closures).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that optionals (in this case `(()-> Int)?`) are an Enum which capture their value. If that value is a function, it must be used with `@escaping` because it is indeed captured by the optional. 
In your case it gets tricky because the closure captured by the optional automatically captures another closure. So `someOtherClosure` has to be marked `@escaping` as well.

You can test the following code in a playground to confirm this:

```
extension Array
{
    private func someFunction(someClosure: () -> Int)
    {
        // Do Something
    }

    func someOtherFunction(someOtherClosure: () -> Int)
    {
        someFunction(someClosure: someOtherClosure)
    }
}

let f: ()->Int = { return 42 }

[].someOtherFunction(someOtherClosure: f)
```

Comment: `Optional` isn't opaque – it's an `enum` and is perfectly transparent.

Comment: As @Hamish says, optional is `enum Optional<T> { case some(T), case none }` Lots of the "quirks" of optionals become clear when you remember this.