# Should self be used in all the closures or just the ones marked with @escaping?

Tags: ios, swift

In the latest Swift [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) it is mentioned that

> Marking a closure with @escaping means you have to refer to self explicitly within the closure.

and in the following method on UIView

```
animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Swift.Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```

The **@escaping** is only for the first closure parameter, but still in the second closure I'm required to use self or else it gives the following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usKt1.png)

setUpButton() is a method in my class

Why is this so? Do I have to use self in all the closures or just the ones marked with **@escaping**.

Comment: You are obligated to use self in escaping closures only. But optional closures are implicitly escaping whereas non-optional closures are implicitly non-escaping and can be marked as escaping with the `@escaping` keyword.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200857/trouble-with-non-escaping-closures-in-swift-3.

Comment: Thanks @deadbeef that really helped!

Comment: thanks @deadbeef for the great point you touched!