# Pass a closure as an optional parameter of the function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a function which takes two parameters, the last parameter is a callback closure:

```
func myAsycTask(name: String, callback: @escaping ()->Void) {
   myQueue.async{
      self.doTask(name)
      callback()
   }
} 

func doTask(name: String) {...}
```

I would like to make the 2nd callback closure parameter optional. I tried to re-define the function above to:

```
func myAsycTask(name: String, callback: @escaping ()->Void? = nil) {
       myQueue.async{
          self.doTask(name)
          callback()
       }
}
```

I get a compiler error:

> Nil default argument value of cannot be converted to type '`() ->`'

How can I achieve what I need then?

Comment: Well [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618803/swift-3-optional-escaping-closure-parameter)

Answer (score 5):

Your current code means that `Void` is an optional return in the closure (which does not make much sense, since `Void` is already nothing). You should **enclose the parameter in brackets** and then make it optional.

```
func myAsycTask(name: String, callback: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

Comment: But then the closure can not be `@escaping` since it's not a closure anymore but an optional closure.

Comment: Oh well spotted! Thanks! I wasn't aware of that myself, so good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Try making your callback closure **Optional** and remove **@escaping**.
**@escaping** annotation is pointless because your parameter is basically an enum (Optional is an enum with 2 cases: some(Value) and none)
If your closure is owned by another type it is implicitly escaping.

```
import UIKit

// Also you can use a typealias to keep code more readable
typealias Callback = (() -> Void)

class Test {

    let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.playground")

    func doTask(name: String) {
        // something...
    }

    func myAsycTask(name: String, callback: Callback? = nil) {
        myQueue.async { [weak self] in
            self?.doTask(name: name)
            callback?()
        }
    }
}
```