# Swift optional escaping closure

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

[image]

Compiler error `Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completion' may allow it to escape`, Which make sense because it will be called after the function return.

```
func sync(completion:(()->())) {
    self.remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: TimeInterval(expirationDuration)) { (status, error) -> Void in
        completion()
    }
}
```

---

But if I make closure optional then no compiler error, Why is that? closure can still be called after the function returns.

```
func sync(completion:(()->())?) {
    self.remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: TimeInterval(expirationDuration)) { (status, error) -> Void in
        completion?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39618803/2976878 (specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39846519/2976878)

Comment: Possibly not exactly a duplicate, but many thanks for those links @Hamish

Comment: Here's an [excellent article by Ole Begemann](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/optional-non-escaping-closures/) that describes why it's happening and some workarounds if you want optional parameters to be @noescape.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Clarification:

For understanding the case, implementing the following code would be useful:

```
typealias completion = () -> ()

enum CompletionHandler {
    case success
    case failure

    static var handler: completion {
        get { return { } }
        set { }
    }
}

func doSomething(handlerParameter: completion) {
    let chObject = CompletionHandler.handler = handlerParameter
}
```

At the first look, this code seems to be legal, but it's not! you would get compile-time error complaining:

> **error**: assigning non-escaping
>   parameter 'handlerParameter' to an @escaping closure
>
> let chObject = CompletionHandler.handler = handlerParameter

with a note that:

> **note**: parameter 'handlerParameter' is implicitly non-escaping func
>   doSomething(handlerParameter: completion) {

Why is that? the assumption is that the code snippet has nothing to do with the `@escaping`...

Actually, since Swift 3 has been released, the closure will be "escaped" if it's declared in *enum*, *struct* or *class* by default.

As a reference, there are bugs reported related to this issue:

- [Optional closure type is always considered @escaping](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2324).
- [@escaping failing on optional blocks](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2444).

Although they might not 100% related to this case, the assignee comments are clearly describe the case:

[First comment](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2324?focusedCommentId=17010&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17010):

> The actual issue here is that **optional closures are implicitly
>   @escaping right now.**

[Second comment](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2444?focusedCommentId=17909&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17909):

> That is unfortunately the case for Swift 3. Here are the semantics for
>   escaping in Swift 3:
>
> 1) Closures in function parameter position are
>   non-escaping by default
>
> 2) **All other closures are escaping**
>
> Thus, all generic type argument closures, such as Array and **Optional**, are escaping.

*Obviously, `Optional` is enum.*

Also -as mentioned above-, the same behavior would be applicable for the classes and structs:

**Class Case:**

```
typealias completion = () -> ()

class CompletionHandler {
    var handler: () -> ()

    init(handler: () -> ()) {
        self.handler = handler
    }
}

func doSomething(handlerParameter: completion) {
    let chObject = CompletionHandler(handler: handlerParameter)
}
```

**Struct Case:**

```
typealias completion = () -> ()

struct CompletionHandler {
    var handler: completion
}

func doSomething(handlerParameter: completion) {
    let chObject = CompletionHandler(handler: handlerParameter)
}
```

The two above code snippets would leads to the same output (compile-time error).

*For fixing the case, you would need to let the function signature to be*:

```
func doSomething( handlerParameter: @escaping completion)
```

### Back to the Main Question:

Since you are expecting that you have to let the `completion:(()->())?` to be escaped, that would automatically done -as described above-.

Answer (score 28):

Wrapping a closure in an Optional automatically marks it escaping. It's technically already "escaped" by being embedded into an enum (the Optional).

Comment: why is that the case though? What's the idea behind this?

Comment: Fascinating. I suppose this is because, being assigned as a property value inside a wrapper, it has been escaped already.

Comment: @matt Exactly. If you stick a closure inside a struct, it also is automatically "escaping."

Comment: @matt yes I understand how optional works, but this was not obvious to me. Very interesting!

Comment: They should consider using the first sentence as the error message.