# Optional @escaping Closure?

Tags: swift, closures, swift4.2

I want to use Optional @escaping closures to execute something when the closure is called in the function, but if i make it optional like that:

```
func checkForFavorites(_ completion: (@escaping (Bool) -> Void)?) {

}
```

i get this error

> @escaping attribute may only be used in function parameter position

This may be an easy question so please have understanding

Comment: Optional closures are always escaping. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417920/swift-optional-escaping-closure?rq=1

Comment: `(@escaping (Bool) -> Void)?)` => `@escaping ((Bool) -> Void)?)`?

Comment: Larme: @escaping attribute only applies to function types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 optional escaping closure parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618803/swift-3-optional-escaping-closure-parameter)