# Optional Completion Handler with no parameters

Tags: swift, swift4

I basically want to have an optional completion handler that has no parameters that are passed back. Here is what I have so far but obviously it is wrong.

```
func refreshAccountData(type:String, completion: (()->(Void))?){
    //Network call is made
    Alamofire.request... {
        completion?()
        //Here is where I want to call the optional completion handler
    }

}
```

I don't want to pass any parameters in the completion block. I just want to know when the network call has been completed so I can refresh the UI. I don't want to refresh the UI here because I want this to act as a generic function for refreshing data. The reason I want the completion handler to be optional is because sometimes I don't need to do anything after the refresh is done.

I am very confused about what @escaping means as well. I usually have it when I do things like this but any clarity would be great. I have done some homework about it online but not found much that I really get.

Comment: What's wrong with it? It is not obvious, I just used the same declaration without a compiler error..

Comment: really? this is the best way to do it? I don't have to worry about anything relating to escaping and I don't need to force unwrap the `completion?()`. I believe Xcode makes me for unwrap the `completion!()`

Comment: Why not simply `func refreshAccountData(type:String, completion: @escaping ()->()){` and just call `completion()`? If you don't want to execute anything just pass am empty closure when calling your method

Comment: Another option is to set a default value to your completion handler so you can simply omit the closure when calling your method `func refreshAccountData(type:String, completion: @escaping (()->()) = {}){`

Answer (score 11):

First, drop the brackets around `Void` type:

```
func refreshAccountData(type:String, completion: (() -> Void)?){
    //Network call is made
    Alamofire.request... {
        completion?() 
    }
}
```

If you force unwrap a closure call, you are basically saying that you know that there will always be a completion callback. But in your case you explicitly mentioned that you want an optional, so calling `completion?()` is what you want.

Regarding escaping, optional closures are implicitly escaped, so if you want a non-escaping version, you would have to use non-optional closure. Read the Escaping Closures section in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) to learn more about escaping. Basically, in your case you need an escaping closure, because you use `completion` in the asynchronous callback, which executes *after* the `refreshAccountData` finishes. But again, as I said, making the closure optional makes it implicitly escaping (read more in [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618803/swift-3-optional-escaping-closure-parameter)).

Now you know that your `completion` is escaping - what does it mean? Simply put, if it is non-escaping, compiler will guarantee that the `completion` closure gets released after the `refreshAccountData` method finishes, thus in effect all the resources captured by the `completion` would be released, too. Escaping `completion` closure however can live longer that during the `refreshAccountData` call - meaning that it can possible create retain cycles (the closure might be keeping live strong references to `self` and other objects, which might be because of that retained).

Now in your case, since you want an optional `completion` closure, you have no other way than simply to accept it is escaping - so how can you make sure `completion` closure won't keep unwanted strong references? You can simply use capture list (see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56) for reference) when creating the completion to make sure that even `self` is just a weak reference and it won't be retained because of the closure:

```
refreshAccountData(type: "") { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using a Default Value

I don't prefer to use optional for completion handlers. So I use the default value for solution. Thanks for @Leo Dabus's comment.

```
func refreshAccountData(type:String, completion: @escaping (()->()) = {}){ 

}
```

##### Call Without Copletion

Here is how you can call without a completion handler.

```
refreshAccountData(type: "SomeTypeHere")
```

##### Call With Copletion

```
refreshAccountData(type: "") {
    
}
```