# Does Objective-C have an equivalent to Swift's @escaping annotation?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Swift, escaping closure parameters are annotated with `@escaping`. Is there any equivalent in Objective-C so that the generated Swift interfaces will be marked as `@escaping`?

Comment: Objective C doesn't distinguish been escaping and non-escaping blocks, so it wouldn't surprise me if all ObjC interfaces imported into Swift as escaping.

Comment: It would be manual but does NS_SWIFT_NAME allow you to pass that info across

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, but it's backwards from what you suggest in your question. The rule is that an Objective-C nonnullable block is translated into Swift as an `@escaping` function *automatically*, unless it is explicitly marked `(NS_NOESCAPE ^)`.

Comment: This probably goes back to before the time when we had `@escaping` and we had `@noescape` instead. So that got baked into Objective-C and now there's no point changing it even though Swift has switched polarities, as it were.

Comment: Just a remark (because that bit me): You'll see the @escaping in the Swift generated interface only if the Objective-C block parameter is marked as _Nonnull. Otherwise it is imported as IUO, and those are escaping by default.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I see that a `(^ __nullable)` block lacks the `@escaping` parameter even though it does in fact escape. Hmmm.

Comment: Optional closures are “implicitly escaping:” https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2324, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39846519/1187415, https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/optional-non-escaping-closures/.

Comment: @MartinR So weird. - I've added "nonnullable" into my statement of the rule.

Comment: @matt More likely, I think the default behaviors in Objective-C have remained backward-compatible with older Obj-C/C code code, with annotations for modern code safety assertions.  This has made writing ObjC in modern times more messy with annotations _(when was the last time you saw an Obj-C header that didn’t have `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN`/`END` and  `nullable` littered throughout?),_ but non-annotated Obj-C works (unsafely) the same as it always has, and annotated Obj-C bridges nicely into Swift.