# Make a function that is passed as an argument to another function optional?

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing, option-type, uialertcontroller

I have an extension to `UIAlertController` that I am using to show a pop-up of the Terms of Service in my app.

I would like to have two versions of this pop-up: One where the user can accept or decline the ToS (to be displayed on first use of the app), and one where the user can read over them and then **dismiss** the pop-up (to be displayed in the settings screen at any time).

The two pop-ups are extremely similar, so instead of rewriting the same function twice, I'd rather create another function that calls `termsOfServiceAlert()` with modified arguments. However, since the user should only be able to dismiss the ToS when `termsOfServiceAlternativeAlert()` is called, I need to make the `accept` and `decline` arguments **optional**. I know how to do this for normal variables, but I can't find a way to make it work for functions that are passed as arguments.

Here is the code snippet:

```
extension UIAlertController {

    static func termsOfServiceAlert(
        title: String,
        message: String?,
        acceptText: String,
        accept: @escaping ()->Void,
        declineText: String,
        decline: @escaping ()->Void) -> UIAlertController {

            /* set up alert */

            let acceptTermsHandler: (UIAlertAction) -> Void = { (alertAction in
                accept()
            }

            let declineTermsHandler: (UIAlertAction) -> Void = { (alertAction in
                decline()
            }

            let accept = "Accept"
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: accept, style: .default, handler: acceptTermsHandler

            let decline = "Decline"
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: decline, style: .default, handler: declineTermsHandler

            return alert
    }

    static func termsOfServiceAlternativeAlert(message: String, dismiss: String) -> UIAlertController {
        /* ERROR - Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '() -> Void */
        return termsOfService(
            message: message, 
            acceptText: dismiss, 
            accept: nil, 
            declineText: nil, 
            decline: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the argument type `(() -> Void)?`

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618803/swift-3-optional-escaping-closure-parameter

Comment: I tried that, it won't work.

Comment: @dan that doesn't work in this case because there's no good place to put the `@escaping` keyword without creating a syntax error.

Comment: @leftspin You don't need the `@escaping` keyword for optional closure parameters.

Comment: @dan ah yeah, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make those arguments as `optional` and then pass as `nil`. here is the fix,

```
extension UIAlertController {

    static func termsOfServiceAlert(
        title: String,
        message: String?,
        acceptText: String,
        accept: (()->Void)?,
        declineText: String?,
        decline: (()->Void)?) -> UIAlertController {

        /* set up alert */

       let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
       let acceptTermsHandler: (UIAlertAction) -> Void = { alertAction in
          accept?()
       }

       let declineTermsHandler: (UIAlertAction) -> Void = { alertAction in
           decline?()
        }

       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .default, handler: acceptTermsHandler))

       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .default, handler: declineTermsHandler))

       return alert
  }

    static func termsOfServiceAlternativeAlert(message: String, dismiss: String) -> UIAlertController {
        /* ERROR - Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '() -> Void */
        return termsOfServiceAlert(
            title: "", 
            message: message,
            acceptText: dismiss,
            accept: nil,
            declineText: nil,
            decline: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kamran. I am curious as to why we need to remove `@escaping` when passing the function as an `optional`!