# How to fix : "passing non-escaping parameter to function expecting @escaping closure"

Tags: swift, generics, escaping, closures

I'm experimenting usage of closurse for First Order Predicate calculus, and
I intend to define the following function :

```
func ASSUM<U, V>(p: @escaping Pred<U>) -> (Pred<U>) -> Pred<(U, V)> {
    return { q in AND1(p: p, q: q) }
}
```

that takes as parameter a predicate `p: Pred<U>`, where `Pred<U>` is a typealias for `(T) -> Bool`:

```
typealias Pred<T> = (T) -> Bool
```

The return of `ASSUM` is a Predicate transformer closure of type `(Pred<U>)->Pred<(U,V)>`.

However the compiler return the following error :

> ```
> Passing non-escaping parameter 'q' to function expecting an @escaping closure
> ```

I understand that the function `AND1` as defined requests an escaping parameter :

```
func AND1<U, V>(p: @escaping Pred<U>, q: @escaping Pred<V>) -> Pred<(U, V)> {
    return { (x, y) in (p(x) && q(y)) }
}
```

but I did not succeed in explicitly making `q` in `{ q in AND1(p: p, q: q) }` escaping.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating closures to Swift 3 - @escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063499/updating-closures-to-swift-3-escaping)

Answer (score 1):

You must explictly add the `@escaping` attribute to the argument of the return type closure of `ASSUM`:

```
typealias Pred<T> = (T)->Bool

func AND1<U, V>(p: @escaping Pred<U> , q: @escaping Pred<V>) -> Pred<(U, V)> {
    return { (x,y) in (p(x) && q(y)) }
}

func ASSUM<U, V>(p: @escaping Pred<U>) -> (@escaping Pred<V>) -> Pred<(U, V)> { 
                                                       /* ^ note: I believe you 
                                                            want V here, not U  */
    return { AND1(p: p, q: $0) }
}
```

In the returned closure, `q` (anonymous `$0` argument) is correctly inferred as `@escaping` (and needn't be explicitly marked as such, as pointed out by @Hamish, thanks!).

Note also that the generic type `V` in `ASSUM` must be inferred by explicit type annotation (or conversion) *by the caller*, as it is not included in any of the arguments to `ASSUM`.

```
/* example usage */
let foo = { $0 < 2 }
let bar = { $0 != "bar" }

let fooAnd: (@escaping Pred<String>) -> Pred<(Int, String)> = ASSUM(p: foo)
let fooAndBar = fooAnd(bar)

print(fooAndBar((1, "foo"))) // true
print(fooAndBar((1, "bar"))) // false
print(fooAndBar((2, "foo"))) // false
```

Finally, `ALLCAPITAL` function names is not in line with the Swift naming convention: you should prefer `camelCase` naming instead (see e.g. the [Swift API guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) for additional details).

Comment: The solution wasn't quite the explicit type annotation, it was the adding `@escaping` to `Pred<V>` in the function signature – you can feel free to remove the explicit type annotation from the closure, and let type inference do the rest :)

Comment: @dfri  thank for help, and recommandations. I can now pursue my experiments. (And yes your right I'll will rewrite my code using camelCase ;-))

Comment: @Clause happy to help!