# Swift closure using firebase blocks compile

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

I'm following an online class (from December, 2016) and am getting the error in this screenshot.

[image: error screenshot]

Here's my code:
        //
    //  FirebaseManager.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAnalytics

class FirebaseManager: NSObject {
    static let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    static var currentUserId:String = ""
    static var currentUser:FIRUser? = nil

    static func Login(email:String, password:String, completion: @escaping (_ success:Bool) ->
        Void) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user,error)
            in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        } else {
            curentUser = user
            currentUserId = (user?.uid)!
            completion(true)}
        })
    }
}
```

And here is the screenshot of the code from this example:[image: code example from class]

I've reviewed a few SO questions including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063499/updating-closures-to-swift-3-escaping) but don't see an answer that applies to my situation. 
Please see my attached[my swift version settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlWAB.jpg) swift settings. [image: Xcode version] Attaching again as I don't see it. [image: Swift Version settings]

Thanks for your help

Comment: try removing _ success from completion & just type `completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)`

Comment: That didn't seem to help. Can you explain the reason for your recommendation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using legacy Swift instead of Swift 3? The sample code you show is for Swift 3. The `@escaping` attribute was introduced in Swift 3, so that could explain the build error.